# How to fix operand type clash : image is incomplate with varchar(max) in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a user defined type (with script to CREATE) given below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeMasters](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[EmployeeID] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[EmployeeFName] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[EmployeeLName] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
[Photo] [image] NOT NULL)
```

On the same database I have created a procedure that uses this type:

```
create PROCEDURE EmpQuli_INSERT @EmployeeID varchar(Max),@EmployeeFName VARCHAR(MAX), @EmployeeLName VARCHAR(MAX),@Photo IMAGE AS BEGIN DECLARE @NEWID VARCHAR(10);  

DECLARE @PREFIX VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @PREFIX = UPPER(SUBSTRING('STR',1, 3)) SELECT @NEWID = (@PREFIX + replicate('0', 3 -len(CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.OID + 1))) + CONVERT(VARCHAR,N.OID + 1)) FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(T.TID) IS null then 0 else MAX(T.TID) end as OID FROM (SELECT SUBSTRING(EmployeeID, 3, 1) as PRE_FIX,SUBSTRING(EmployeeID, 3, LEN(EmployeeID))as TID FROM EmployeeMasters) AS T WHERE T.PRE_FIX = @PREFIX) AS N
insert into EmployeeMasters values(@NEWID,@EmployeeFName, @EmployeeLName,  @Photo);
 end
```

And I try to insert a value in c# I getting ***operand type clash : image is incomplate with varchar(max) in sql server***
 The c# code is:

```
EmployeeFName.Value = textBox_emp_Fname.Text;
EmployeeLName.Value = textBox_emp_Lname.Text;
Photo.Value =img_arr1;

AddEmployee.CommandText = "EmpQuli_INSERT @EmployeeFName, @EmployeeLName, @Photo";
```

I don't know who to fix it. Please help me because I have to submit my final year project on June first week but now I struggle this exception please help....

Comment: What is `img_arr1`? What is `Photo.Value`? How are the parameters assigned?

Comment: I Converted a image to Byte[]  Using this Code: MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox_emp_photo_browse.Image.Save(ms1, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                if (ms1.Length > 25000)
                    MessageBox.Show("Please upload less than 25 kb image");
                byte[] img_arr1 = new byte[ms1.Length];
               
                ms1.Read(img_arr1, 0, img_arr1.Length);

Comment: MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
                pictureBox_emp_photo_browse.Image.Save(ms1, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                if (ms1.Length > 25000)
                    MessageBox.Show("Please upload less than 25 kb image");
                byte[] img_arr1 = new byte[ms1.Length];
               
                ms1.Read(img_arr1, 0, img_arr1.Length

Comment: And if you use `ms1.ToArray()`?

Comment: No I'm not using ms1.ToArray()

Comment: I know, and when you do, does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a column in your insert statement:

```
insert into EmployeeMasters values(@NEWID,@EmployeeFName, @EmployeeLName,  @Photo);
```

EmployeeID is missing, so `@Photo` tries to save into `@EmployeeLName`, which is incompatible. Even if it weren't, you'd still be missing `EmployeeID`, which is `NOT NULL`.

I'd suggest using the explicit insert syntax instead of relying on the auto-supplied columns:

```
insert into EmployeeMasters(EmployeeID, EmployeeFName, EmployeeLName, Photo)
  values (@NewID, @EmployeeFName, @EmployeeLName, @Photo);
```

Comment: But I already assigned a values EmployeeID to @NewID Code is: 'SELECT SUBSTRING(EmployeeID, 3, 1) as PRE_FIX,SUBSTRING(EmployeeID, 3, LEN(EmployeeID)) as TID FROM EmployeeMasters'

Comment: @MeenaS Sure, but you didn't supply `ID`. You can't just leave out columns randomly and expect everything to work. Just because `ID` is an identity column doesn't mean that its skipped in an `insert`. Just name the columns explicitly and your problem is solved.